# Commanding numerous motors with one H-Bridge

Tags: transistors, mosfet, motor, h-bridge

Is it possible to command more than one motor with an H-bridge like this:

[image]

Would this work in real life if I replace switches with transistors and command them?

Comment: It might be quite tricky to drive those transistors you want to use to replace the switches.

Answer (score 2):

An H-bridge enables current to flow in both directions, and hence drives a motor in both directions.

A single transistor is not enough to control current current flow in both directions.

Hence, each mechanical switch would be replaced by two transistors.

At that point, the circuit uses the same number of transistors are two H-Bridges. So it is easier to make two H-Bridges.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason it can't work, but remember that the switches in series with the motors must be bi-directional switches.  (MOSFETS have body diodes allowing current to flow in one direction even when off.)  You could use two FETs in a back-to-back configuration, or you could use a relay.